# Unable to allocate more than one CPU to my Map/Reduce Job in Hortonworks

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I am running HDP 2.4.2 version on 5 Node cluster.
Whenever i am launching any job on cluster they are only taking one CPU instead on the configured CPU.

I have configured 4 CPU but my jobs are only taking one CPU.

I have five 24 Cores 128 GB Ubuntu boxes in my cluster.

Please let me know if this is a limitation with HDP because it was working fine with cloudera

**EDIT**

```
<property>
 <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
<value>15</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
<value>15</value>
</property>
```

Comment: What is value of yarn.scheduler.minimun-allocation-vcore in yarn-site.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution for this problem

CPU scheduling must be enabled on the cluster by default it is set to disable. After enabling the CPU scheduling on the cluster it started providing requested CPUs to my jobs.

`yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator` is the property Name. Search it in yarn configuration and enable it. The default value for this property is `DefaultResourceCalculator` which will be overridden by `DominantResourceCalculator` once we enable the CPU scheduling.

Ref link: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.3/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/enabling_cpu_scheduling.html